# how to print array as a table in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print an array like: 
`Table = [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)]`.

Therefore, I want to print this array as a table like:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
```

How can I make this?

I tried a simple `print Table` but this prints the array like this:

```
[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried a basic `for` loop?

```
for line in Table:
    print ' '.join(map(str, line))
```

It's prettier in Python 3:

```
for line in Table:
    print(*line)
```

Comment: You also can separate columns by a tab, to make it easier to visualize: `for line in Table:
    print('\t'.join(map(str, line)))`.

Answer (score 4):

In python3 you can print array as a table in one line:

```
[print(*line) for line in table]
```

Answer (score 2):

@Tigerhawk's answer is very good if you want something simple.

For other cases, I highly suggest using the ***[tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)*** module, allowing great flexibility, and overcoming potential problems like few-digit ints which would cause shifting:

```
1 2 3
1 12 3
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PrettyTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable) package:

**Example for your variable (`Table`) with three columns:**

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def makePrettyTable(table_col1, table_col2, table_col3):
    table = PrettyTable()
    table.add_column("Column-1", table_col1)
    table.add_column("Column-2", table_col2)
    table.add_column("Column-3", table_col3)
    return table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
for item in [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)]:
  temp = (' '.join(str(s) for s in item) + '\n') 
  print(string.replace(temp, '\n', ''))
```

Test

```
   $ python test.py 
    0 0 0
    0 0 1
    0 1 0
```

Comment: What is the point of adding a newline and then replacing it? And why `import string` for that? It's extra running in circles for no reason.

Comment: Correct output is the best point. What did you try: Voting and commenting. What a programmer...a voter and a commenter.

Comment: @Programmer400 He wrote the accepted answer, that's what he did. And why *did* you add then remove the newline?

Answer (score -1):

I usually do something like this:

```
def printMatrix(s):

    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(len(s[0])):
            print("%5d " % (s[i][j]), end="")
        print('\n')
```

And this code gives you column and row numbers:

```
def printMatrix(s):

    # Do heading
    print("     ", end="")
    for j in range(len(s[0])):
        print("%5d " % j, end="")
    print()
    print("     ", end="")
    for j in range(len(s[0])):
        print("------", end="")
    print()
    # Matrix contents
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print("%3d |" % (i), end="") # Row nums
        for j in range(len(s[0])):
            print("%5d " % (s[i][j]), end="")
        print()
```

The output looks like this:

```
         0     1     2 
     ------------------
  0 |    0     0     0 
  1 |    0     0     1 
  2 |    0     1     0
```

Comment: Python has excellent syntax for iterating over sequences without needing to mess with indices.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, yeah I know this, but I want the indices.  I could use enumerate I guess, but it doesn't really add anything.

Comment: The OP is using Python 2, by the way, and you're using features that require `print()` as a function (and I don't see the necessary import). On top of being a reinvention of the wheel (see other answers for modules to print tables in a fancy way), this flat-out won't work.

Comment: Did they say they were using Python 2? I don't see that. Your answer is just too basic mate,  what about formatting? Numbers with differing numbers of digits etc?

Comment: And my earlier comment wasn't about using `range(len(...`; it was about iterating over indices like an old-style `for (int i=0; i++; i<array.length()) {...`. There's zero need for that here.

Comment: Yes, they did say that. "I tried a simple `print Table`". And "too basic" is a sign of good Python code, not to mention that it's what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for row and column numbers, nor did s/he require the ability to print more than 1-digit numbers. If they had, adding a simple [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) would do it. Your answer is *overly* complex (see above comments about iterating through indices), and could be done better by using one of the many table-printing modules out there. OP is clearly using Python 2 with the reference to `print Table`. Finally, don't get your panties in a knot about constructive criticism. Learn the lesson and move on.